# How can I impove this JOIN operation between key table and another

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

My problem is that I have two different queries that work well in different 
situations.

SCHEMA

```
  messages 
      message_id, entity_id, message, timestamp

   subscription
      user_id, entity_id

   users
      user_id

   entities
      entity_id
```

Situation 1: Lots of message entries, and at least one relevant subscription entry

Situation 2: Few message entries and/or few, or zero, subscription entries that are relevant

My Two Queries are:

```
 SELECT messages.*
   FROM messages
   STRAIGHT_JOIN subscription ON subscription.entity_id = messages.entity_id
   WHERE subscription.user_id = 1
   ORDER BY messages.timestamp DESC 
   LIMIT 50
```

This query works well in situation 1 (.000x seconds):  Lots of message entries, and at least one relevant subscription entry. thisquery will take 1.7+ seconds in situation 2.

```
 SELECT messages.*
   FROM messages
   INNER JOIN subscription ON subscription.entity_id = messages.entity_id
   WHERE subscription.user_id = 1
   ORDER BY messages.timestamp DESC 
   LIMIT 50
```

This query works well in situation 2 (.000x seconds):  Few message entries and/or few, or zero, subscription entries that are relevant. This query will take 1.3+ seconds in situation 1.

Is there a query that I can use that can get the best of both worlds? If not, what's the best way to 
handle this case?

Indexes:

```
( subscription.user_id, subscription.entity_id )
( subscription.entity_id )
( messages.entity_id, messages.timestamp )
( messages.timestamp )
```

EXPLAIN INFO

LIMIT 50

```
| id | select_type | table             | type   | possible_keys                           | key           | key_len | ref                                    | rows | Extra       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | messages          | index  | idx_timestamp                           | idx_timestamp | 4       | NULL                                   |   50 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | subscription      | eq_ref | PRIMARY,entity_id,user_id               | PRIMARY       | 16      | const, messages.entity_id              |    1 | Using index |
```

Without Limit

```
| id | select_type | table             | type   | possible_keys                           | key           | key_len | ref                                    |   rows   | Extra         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | messages          | ALL    | entity_id_2,entity_id                   | NULL          | NULL    | NUL                                    |   255069 | Using filesort|
|  1 | SIMPLE      | subscription      | eq_ref | PRIMARY,entity_id,user_id               | PRIMARY       | 16      | const, messages.entity_id              |        1 | Using index   |
```

CREATE TABLE STATEMENTS:

With ~5000 rows

```
subscription | CREATE TABLE `subscription` (
  `user_id`   bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `entity_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`entity_id`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

with ~255,000 rows

```
messages | CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `message_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entity_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`message_id`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`,`timestamp`),
  KEY `idx_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `WHERE` with a `AND`

```
SELECT messages.*
   FROM messages
   STRAIGHT_JOIN subscription ON subscription.entity_id = messages.entity_id
        AND subscription.user_id = 1
   ORDER BY messages.timestamp DESC 
   LIMIT 50
```

OR

```
SELECT messages.*
   FROM messages
   INNER JOIN subscription ON subscription.entity_id = messages.entity_id
           AND subscription.user_id = 1
   ORDER BY messages.timestamp DESC 
   LIMIT 50
```

OR may be this way :

```
SELECT messages.*
FROM subscription 
STRAIGHT_JOIN messages ON subscription.entity_id = messages.entity_id
WHERE subscription.user_id = 1
ORDER BY messages.timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but they don't seem to fix the issue.